# How to find questions originating from papers?

Tags: discussion, support, search

What is a reasonable way to find questions which are related to mathematical papers?

The motivation to ask this was a [recent post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25150/is-my-question-too-hard/25151#25151) mentioning that:

> However the focus of this site seems to be drifting ever further towards questions from elementary/introductory courses, so a question based on results from a research article is put at a great disadvantage. There are fewer users able to actually answer the question, and the time it spends on the front page is much less ... At the same time in the reputation economy of Math Stack Exchange there is little incentive to answer advanced questions: they generally take more time and effort to answer, and at the same time receive much less attention/votes.

Another (much older) posts related to this are [Concern about lesser attention towards relatively advanced questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11936/concern-about-lesser-attention-towards-relatively-advanced-questions), [Proposal for promoting more interesting, deeper questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13472/proposal-for-promoting-more-interesting-deeper-questions) and probably a few others.

I agree that if some user has knowledge to answer a question from a research article, this is probably time better spent than answering some basic calculus or linear algebra question (considering that there are many users around who can answer basic questions), especially if it is a question which has been asked and answered on this site several times before. This is also in the spirit of the suggestion given here: [Letting less-reputable people answer questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7178/letting-less-reputable-people-answer-questions).

I am aware of some suggestions how to find more interesting (more difficult) questions: 
[What can users do to improve their Math.SE experience?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8626/what-can-users-do-to-improve-their-math-se-experience) or the MO post [Interesting (and not sufficiently answered) questions on math.SE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1967/interesting-and-not-sufficiently-answered-questions-on-math-se) (created manually). And [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9249/proposal-make-the-interesting-tab-the-default-on-math-se-homepage/14963#14963) mentions a bookmarklet for this purpose. However, here I am asking specifically about questions originating from/related to papers.

The only idea I had was to use search and try to search for some reasonable keywords (probably intersected with tag from the areas I know enough about), such as [paper](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=paper+intags%3amine%20is%3aq), [doi](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=doi+intags%3amine%20is%3aq), [arxiv](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=arxiv+intags%3amine%20is%3aq), [url:doi.org](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=url:doi.org+intags%3amine%20is%3aq), [url:arxiv.org](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=url:arxiv.org+intags%3amine%20is%3aq). (I guess a suggestion how to make list of reasonable keywords for searching more complete could also be an acceptable answer to my question.)

Comment: If you like this meta question, you may also want to support a proposal for [trackbacks from SE to the arXiv](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240520/209806).

Answer (score 9):

I often suggest [JSTOR's free Register & Read access option](http://about.jstor.org/rr) for papers that are otherwise behind paywalls.  In any case this query:

```
is:question url:jstor.org
```

on the main Math.SE site returns 239 posts at present.

A fairly naive query:

```
is:question theorem reading paper
```

returns 273 posts at present, many of which seem of interest per the OP.

Comment: In the same spirit, one can talk about MR links.

Comment: The intersection of the two suggested searches, by the way, contains six results at this moment.